# Firestore document update

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `set` method on Typescript Cloud Functions. Apparently if the document exists, we will `update` the document. In Flutter, the StreamBuilder method is not triggered if the document on Firestore is the same as the document I am pushing to Firestore i.e. when the documents before and after updating are the same.

Is this because, Firestore `update` method does not return anything when documents before and after update are the same? Or it is because StreamBuilder in Flutter is not triggered for the same reason?

How can I solve this issue i.e. how can I have StreamBuilder in Flutter triggered when I have used `updated` method on Firestore when there has not been any changes on the document I updated?

*I do not want to use `delete` method if document exists and then create the document for triggering StreamBuilder because this will trigger StreamBuilder twice and not a nice way.

Comment: Maybe easiest solution would be adding a property called updateTimestamp to the document and update it when you do update, even other fields are not changed.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `update` method in Firestore, it only performs an update operation if the data you provide is different from the existing document. If the data is the same, Firestore considers it an idempotent operation, meaning it doesn't make any changes to the document.

As a result, the `StreamBuilder` in your Flutter app doesn't receive any updates because Firestore doesn't trigger a change event when there are no actual changes to the document.

To work around this issue and ensure that the `StreamBuilder` is triggered even when the document is the same after an update, you can consider a combination of the `set` and `merge` options.

By using set with merge: true, you can trigger the `StreamBuilder` even when there are no changes to the document. The `set` operation will essentially perform a `merge` operation and trigger an update event in Firestore, which will then be received by the `StreamBuilder` in your Flutter app.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('your_collection')
    .doc('your_document_id')
    .set(yourData, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Comment: If I use "merge" then I have to check if the document on Firestore is exactly the same as the document I am trying to push to Firestore then, otherwise I will keep the items which I had on Firestore which I do not have in my request. "merge" is only updating the items you have in your request and leaves the rest untouched which is not what I want.